# PWA was not loading after run YARN RUN WATCH command

Tags: magento2, pwa, pwa-studio

I am new to PWA. I download and configured PWA from git and run the **yarn run watch** command in the local instance and it shows below error

1. Magento Version : 2.4.3
2. Base URL : http://magento.test/
3. PWA version    : 12.0.1
4. Error Image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaUjO.png

Any once can help me. Is PWA support HTTP requests, because I run magneto locally and its serve from HTTP only not HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment. You need to install magento/pwa in backend. Check this [reply](https://github.com/magento/pwa-studio/issues/3565#issuecomment-976483422)